# How to show the number as astrisk

Tags: java

So I have to show the number of total grades(which i have calculated already) as astrisk. the output should be like this,

```
A=******

B=******

C=******

D=*****
```

And this is my code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;
public class grades 
{

    public static final void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        System.out.println("name");
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("students.txt"));//Creating new scanner object 

            int lineNumber =1;//Line Number for each student.
            while (myScanner.hasNext())
            {

                String firstName = myScanner.next();//Scanning student first name and storing in the string
                String lastName = myScanner.next();// Scanning student last name and storing in the string
                String athleteFlag=myScanner.next();//Scanning for verification of athlete and storing in the string
                String athlete= "Y";
                String notAthlete = "N";
                //if else statement to declare if student is a athlete
                 if (athleteFlag.equals(athlete))
                {
                     athleteFlag="YES";
                }
                 else if(athleteFlag.equals(notAthlete))
                 {
                    athleteFlag="NO";               
                 }
                int quiz1=myScanner.nextInt();// Grades on Quiz 1
                int quiz2=myScanner.nextInt();// Grades on Quiz 2
                int quiz3=myScanner.nextInt();// Grades on Quiz 3
                int quiz4=myScanner.nextInt();// Grades on Quiz 4
                int quiz5=myScanner.nextInt();// Grades on Quiz 5
                int test1=myScanner.nextInt();// Grades on Test 1
                int test2=myScanner.nextInt();// Grades on Test 2
                //student quiz average
                double quizAverage = (double)(quiz1+quiz2+quiz3+quiz4+quiz5)/5;
                //Overall Numerical Grade
                float overallNumericalGrade =(float)(quizAverage+test1+test2)/3;
                //Students letter Grade, eligibility and counting number of each grade
                String grade;
                String eligibility;
                int gradeA=0;
                int gradeB=0;
                int gradeC=0;
                int gradeD=0;
                int gradeF=0;
                    if(overallNumericalGrade>=90.0)
                    {
                        grade="A";
                        eligibility ="YES";
                        gradeA++;
                    }

                    else if(overallNumericalGrade>=80.0)
                    {
                        grade = "B";
                        eligibility ="YES";
                        gradeB++;
                    }
                    else if(overallNumericalGrade>=70.0)    
                    {
                        grade = "C";
                        eligibility ="YES";
                        gradeC++;
                    }
                    else if(overallNumericalGrade>=60.0)
                    {
                        grade = "D";
                        eligibility ="NO";
                        gradeD++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grade = "F";
                        eligibility ="NO";
                        gradeF++;
                    }


                System.out.println(lineNumber + " "+lastName+","+firstName+"/ "+athleteFlag+ "/ " + eligibility +
                        " / " +"Grades on all quiz "+ quiz1+ " "+quiz2+" "+quiz3+" "+ quiz4+" "+quiz5+" "+test1+" "+
                        test2+ " /" +"quiz average is " + quizAverage +"\n " + "Overall Numerical grade is " +
                        overallNumericalGrade+" / "+ "Student letter Grade is " + grade);
                lineNumber++;  

            }

    } 

}
```

I just dont know how to output this. Any help will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume the total of all grade is `overallNumericalGrade` ?

Comment: no thats just the Average of their Quiz average and scores on Test 1 and Test 2. i havnt output the counting yet. as you can see i counted the grade as gradeA++ or GradeB++

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the total of all grade is `overallNumericalGrade` and that you want to display it as `*` in the last output (as this is the only output in your code), You could do

```
System.out.println(lineNumber + " "+lastName+","+firstName+"/ "+athleteFlag+ "/ " + eligibility +
                    " / " +"Grades on all quiz "+ quiz1+ " "+quiz2+" "+quiz3+" "+ quiz4+" "+quiz5+" "+test1+" "+
                    test2+ " /" +"quiz average is " + quizAverage +"\n " + "Overall Numerical grade is " +
                    String.valueOf(overallNumericalGrade).replaceAll(".", "*")+" / "+ "Student letter Grade is " + grade);
```

The important part is here

```
String.valueOf(overallNumericalGrade).replaceAll(".", "*")
```

Where I convert the total value to a String then replace everything with `*`.

If the total is not `overallNumericalGrade` then simply use the replacement on whatever is the value.

**Edit :** To answer to your comment, here more explanation.

`String.replaceAll` is a method that replace everything corresponding to the given `Regular expression(regex)` given by what we give as second parameter ( in that case `*`). The regex I gave is simply a `.` which means any character except linebreak. So, `String.valueOf(overallNumericalGrade)` convert it to a `String` so I can call the `replaceAll` method, then replace everything with `*`.

As for an answer to your second question, once again you could use the  replacement to replace each `linebreak` of `grade` by a simple space so that it display all on the same line. Something like

```
grade.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ");
```

Notice that I used `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of giving in the `char` so that it work on any system.

Comment: i seriously didnt get that. I am fairly new to java. Can you please explain a little bit more. Thanks

Comment: one more problem i am facing is, the grade output is coming 1 by 1 in each line of output because i scanned the variable from different line of the text file. how do i output the grades in one line? thanks

Comment: @MithunIslam See my edit, hope it helps.